# Python requests appending ambersand (&) to URL when adding results from variable as parameter

Tags: python, json

Below is my code which basically retrieves data from the database, puts it into a variable in `CSV` format which I then am trying to append on to a `GET` request URL. However, the get request results in `null` as the `GET` Request URL has an ampersand (`&`) sign in it.

Question is how do I get rid of it?

This is the URL, note the ampersand (`&`):

```
https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/clientsentiment?marketIds=&JGB,BCHUSD,AT20,
```

```
import requests
import json
import time
import datetime
import csv
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

conn_string = "host=' dbname='' user='' password=''"

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

cursor=conn.cursor()
# Query to source marketIds
postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT DISTINCT () FROM static WHERE TYPE!='' AND marketId!='None'"

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
#print("Selecting marketId from table using cursor.fetchall")
instrument_static_marketId = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query )

#This puts the sql result into nice CSV format
y=','.join([y[0] for y in cursor.fetchall() ])
print(y)

# closing database connection.
conn.close ()

def main():
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Origin': 'https://.com',
        'X-IG-API-KEY': '',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-SECURITY-TOKEN': '',
        'CST': '',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Referer': 'https://',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    }

    response = requests.get('https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/clientsentiment?marketIds=',params=y, headers=headers)
    print(response.url)
    result = response.json()
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included part of a parameter in your URL which is incorrect and confused requests.

Leave that off, and pass a dictionary for `params`, just like you're already doing with `headers`:

```
y = 'JGB,BCHUSD,AT20'

params = {
    'marketIDs': y,
}

url = 'https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/clientsentiment'

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's gotten rid of the ampersand but now there is a % sign used a delimiter instead of a comma (,)

Comment: It's not just a `%`, but `%2C`, right? The comma is (correctly) being [URL-encoded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) automatically.

Comment: This is what I see - Sorry total newbie here:                                                                                                                                          https://demo-api.ig.com/gateway/deal/clientsentiment?marketIDs=JGB%2CBCHUSD%2CAT20%2CMXNJPY%2CLGO%2CWALL%2CSGBC%2CCT%2CSUNGBP%2CGBPNOK%2CGBPDKK%2CGBPINR%2CCC%2CHG%2CNICKEL%2CAUDCNH%2CPA

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the comma is correctly being URL encoded?

Comment: Please see my link or google for "url encoding". It's too much to explain here. In short: comma is a reserved character in URLs and needs to be specially encoded. The web server should be expecting it and will see the commas as you intend. That's assuming that the webserver is actually expecting there to be commas there.